# Redireccionar stderr a un fichero

Tags: c, linux, archivo, shell

Estoy intentando crear una funcion en mi shell en c que redireccione el stderr a un fichero en concreto ademas de tener una opcion para volver a dejarlo como estaba y para imprimir a donde esta redireccionando ahora mismo.

Esto es lo que tengo para redireccionar:

```
int backup_fd;//El stderr tiene descriptor 2
int fd;
if ((backup_fd = dup(2)) == -1){
    perror("Error: ");
    return  0;
}
if(close(2) == -1){
    perror("Error: ");
    return 0;
}
if((fd = open(tokens[1], O_RDWR)) == -1){
    perror("Error: ");
    return 0;
}
```

Y ahora no he encontrado nada para la opcion volver a dejarlo como estaba y he probado esto para imprimir el actual despues de leer una pregunta en stackoverflow pero no me imprime el nombre del fichero bien:

```
char buff[1024];
ssize_t a = readlink("/proc/self/fd/2", buff, sizeof(buff));
printf("Error estandar en fichero %s\n", buff); //Imprimir nombre del fichero
return 0;
```

Si a alguien se le ocurre como imprimir el nombre del fichero al que va stderr y como devolver al estado original se lo agradeceria mucho!

Answer (score 0):

Para la opcion de volver al estado original he implementado esto:

```
dup2(backup_fd, STDERR_FILENO);
```

siendo backup_fd la variable que ya declare en el codigo de la pregunta

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o es una ampliación de información de tu pregunta? Si es lo segundo no debería ir en la zona de respuestas. Puedes pulsar el enlace "Editar" bajo la pregunta y añadirle la información que precises.

Comment: Es la respuesta a la primera pregunta que formule, encontre la solucion entonces la deje marcada como respuesta porque es la respuesta a dicha pregunta :)